# How to make the tabs not overflowing the tabs container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

when i add tabs more than the width of the tabs container they go down , i want it to scroll horizontally left and right but not like this example :http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-tabdrop/ 
and thnx.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions out there if you Google "scrollable bootstrap tabs". Alternatively, you can wrap your tabs in two DIVs as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_b" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_c" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_d" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_e" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_f" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_g" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab_h" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab H</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add the following CSS:

```
.scrollable {
  width: 600px;
}

.wrapper    {
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Since this is quite quick-and-dirty, you'll probably want to add more jQuery and CSS to replace the scrollbar with buttons that scroll the tabs left and right, and make sure that the widths of the two DIVs are not hard-coded.

Answer (score -2):

Direct javascript:

```
this.$('.nav-tabs').tabdrop();
```

Use

Call the tabdrop:

```
.tabdrop();
```

Call the tabdrop with options:

```
.tabdrop(options);
```

Options
text

Type: string

Default: icon

```
<i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
```

To change the default value, call

```
.tabdrop({text: "your text here"});
```

when initalizing the tabdrop. The displayed value will change when a tab is selected from the dropdown list.
offsetTop

Type: integer

Default: 0

To change the default value, call

```
.tabdrop({offsetTop: N});
```

when initalizing the tabdrop. This determines when tab has to be included in the dropdown.
Methods
layout

Checks to see if the tabs all fit in one row and displays the text of an active tab in the list:

```
.tabdrop('layout');
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. Wissem specifically said he didn't want to use tabdrop.